# Android : Need help in getting IP Address from hostname

Tags: android, network-programming

I'm using the following tool in my activity and its working. But the output (hostname)  that i get is not the way i want. For example, if i need to find the IP of google, i get it like `www.google.com/74.125.224.72`

it should be just like `74.125.224.72`

I'm new to Android, please help me out. Here's my code :

```
String host = editText1.getText().toString();
try {
    InetAddress[] hostInetAddress = InetAddress.getAllByName(host);
    String all = "";
    for(int i = 0; i < hostInetAddress.length; i++){
        all = all + hostInetAddress[i].toString() + "\n";
    }
    textInetAddress.setText(all);
}
```

Comment: split the value with slash(/)...if all the addresses are coming like you said...

Comment: Should i use it in `all` string?

Comment: where you are getting the value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

get your name/ip_address by using:

```
InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName(new URL(urlString).getHost());
//it will fetch name/ip_address (eg. www.google.com/74.125.224.72) of the url you enter
```

and then get only ip_address using:

```
String ip = address.getHostAddress();
//it will fetch only ip_address (eg. "74.125.224.72" ) from the abouve url
```

so instead of

```
 for(int i = 0; i < hostInetAddress.length; i++){
                    all = all + hostInetAddress[i].toString() + "\n";
                }
```

use the following code

```
 for(int i = 0; i < hostInetAddress.length; i++){
                    all = all + hostInetAddress[i].getHostAddress().toString() + "\n";
                }
```

Comment: instead of 

`  for(int i = 0; i < hostInetAddress.length; i++){
                    all = all + hostInetAddress[i].toString() + "\n";
                }`

use the following code

`  for(int i = 0; i < hostInetAddress.length; i++){
                    all = all + hostInetAddress[i].getHostAddress().toString() + "\n";
                }`

Comment: Thanks, that's what i was looking for. Working like a charm. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
String[] ip = all.split("/");
textInetAddress.setText(ip[1]);
```

Comment: That didn't work, i tried both variables for ip, 

     CharSequence[] ip = null;

    private CharSequence[] ip

creating a force close

Comment: take String[] not charsequence[]

Comment: I did, this was creating an error
 `textInetAddress.setText(ip[1]);`
So to fix it, i needed to set variable     CharSequence[]

Answer (score 0):

No need of for loop. This will work.

```
hostInetAddress[0].getHostAddress();
```

Comment: Thnx, this fixed the problem.
`hostInetAddress[i].getHostAddress()`